# Overlay Scrollbars - Can't get the destroy() method working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I'm using OverlayScrollbars on my website (https://github.com/KingSora/OverlayScrollbars) to display a custom scroll bar in each of my sections.

For design reasons, I want to use this custom scroll bar only for screens above width 1200 px.

I read in the documentation about the destroy() method that would do exactly what I want to achieve : clean the Dom of any style from the custom scroll bar (for me, when screen is getting smaller than 1200 px wide).

When I use the destroy() method, my console returns me the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: instance.destroy is not a function

I'm quite new with JavaScript, so I tried different syntaxes, but always ended up with the same error.

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize >= 1200) {
        //if the window is bigger 1200px wide then turn on ScrollBar..
      $(function() {
        var instance = OverlayScrollbars(document.querySelectorAll("section"), { });
      });
    }
    else if (windowsize < 1200) {
        //if the window is smaller than 440px wide then destroy ScrollBar..
      $(function() {
        var instance = OverlayScrollbars(document.querySelectorAll("section"), { });
        instance.destroy();
      });
    }
}
checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```js
var instance =$ ( '.section' ).overlayScrollbars ( { ... } ).overlayScrollbars()
instance.destroy()
```